# В списке товаров пустые блоки

Tags: css, html

На странице [dev2.softreactor.com/wp-plugings/extended-products-search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05S5n.jpg)
список товаров в 2 колонки но в некоторых случаях (в данном случае если нажать на 2ю страницу паджинации ниже списка )
появляются пустые места и один из товаров отображается ниже и непонятно почему так?

Список товаров отображается через дивы :

```
<div class="row nsn_woo_ext_search_woo_product_next_row col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="nsn_woo_ext_search_next_woo_product">
            <ul class="nsn_woo_ext_search_ul_multiline">
```

А класс имеет пунктирный отображаемый бордюр...

Спасибо !

---

В том то и дело что там некоторые аттрибуты пусты и их НЕ нужно отображать а нужно отображать только заполненный аттрибуты как в  Color: Black в нашем примере
И это еще такой набор данных - что нет длинных имен товаров и нет аттрибутов которые не помещаются в одну строку как например эти данные:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/05S5n.jpg
То есть длинные имена и каждый товар включен в несколько группи поэтому некоторые строки товара разносятся на несколько строк
А если товару еще нафигачить кучу tag-ов?
Поэтому невозможно присвоить высоту каждому диву с товаром(как обычно и делают) и нет возможности присвоить высоту каждой строке аттирбута товара

Нет ли какого решения ?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5263/178988

Answer (score 1):

У вас в блок, под которым исчезла новость, добавлен еще один пункт в описание  **Color: Black** поэтому он выше и вытесняет блок под ним. Надо либо убрать лишний пункт списка, либо задать высоту блоков всем одинаковую.